# How to replace the values of columns with conditions in python DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a DataFrame. How can I replace the values of Returns according to values of other columns? 
the conditions are below:

```
if:Returns > Very_bullish, then Returns=2；
if:Returns > Very_bullish, then Returns=2；
if:Very_bullish > Returns > bullish, then Returns=1；
if:bullish >Returns >bearish,then Returns=0；
if:bearish > Returns > Very_bearish, then Returns=-1；
if:Very_bearish > Returns,then Returns=-2；
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this =)
[pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)
[Some examples of `apply`](https://thispointer.com/pandas-apply-a-function-to-single-or-selected-columns-or-rows-in-dataframe/)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it can not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, I find `np.select` easier to understand. 
Simply we can specify multiple conditions in a list format.

```
import numpy as np

conditions  = [df['Returns'] > df['Very_bullish'],
               df['Very_bullish'] > df['Returns'] > df['bullish'],
               df['bullish'] > df['Returns'] > df['bearish'],
               df['bearish'] > df['Returns'] > df['Very_bearish'],
               df['Very_bearish'] > df['Returns']
               ]
choices     = [2, 1, 0,-1, -2]

df["Returns"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

Here, anything that doesn't match any of the conditions will be replaced by `np.nan`.